# Convert file to base64 string on Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I need to convert image (or any file) to base64 string. I use different ways, but result is always `byte`, not string. Example:

```
import base64

file = open('test.png', 'rb')
file_content = file.read()

base64_one = base64.encodestring(file_content)
base64_two = base64.b64encode(file_content)

print(type(base64_one))
print(type(base64_two))
```

Returned

```
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'bytes'>
```

How do I get a string, not byte? Python 3.4.2.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I need to write base64 text in file, then to read it later.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Base64 is an ascii encoding so you can just decode with ascii

```
>>> import base64
>>> example = b'\x01'*10
>>> example
b'\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01'
>>> result = base64.b64encode(example).decode('ascii')
>>> print(repr(result))
'AQEBAQEBAQEBAQ=='
```

Answer (score 2):

> I need to write base64 text in file ...

So then stop worrying about strings and just do that instead.

```
with open('output.b64', 'wb'):
  write(base64_one)
```

Comment: I great solution but only if you are not also writing other strings to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
import base64

file_text = open(file, 'rb')
file_read = file_text.read()
file_encode = base64.encodebytes(file_read)
```

I initially tried `base64.encodestring()` but that function has been deprecated as per this [issue](https://gitlab.com/flectra-hq/flectra/-/issues/294).

Comment: Watch out -- `base64.encodebytes` will insert `\n` characters "after every 76 bytes of output" per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.encodebytes).